# How to set a variable to two char arrays

Tags: c++

```
char chars[26] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
int a = 7;
int b = 3; 
string attempt;


attempt = chars[a] + chars[b];
cout << attempt;
```

I am trying to set "attempt" to these two arrays but, when i try to display the value of "attempt" it doesn't show anything. I looked through a few places but, they are not showing me the answer.
Also sorry about not clarifying what the arrays are.
Also doing:

```
    attempt += chars[a]
    attempt += chars [b]
```

doesn't seem to work with loops.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
char chars[26] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
string attempt;
string x;
cin >> x;

while (a < 26 && b < 26) {
    attempt = ( attempt + chars[a] ) + chars[b];
    b = b + 1;
    if (attempt == x) {
        cout << "x is: " << attempt;
        break;
    }
    if (b >= 26) {
        a = a + 1;
        b = 0;
    }
    if (a >= 26 && b >= 26) {
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        break;
    }
}


return 0;
```

}

Comment: `chars[a] + chars[b]` will most likely cause `signed char` overflow, which invokes undefined behaviour, anything could happen...

Comment: You can append one character at a time to a string like `attempt += chars[a];`. When you do `chars[a] + chars[b]` this instead adds up the ascii values for the characters, instead of creating a two character string. :-)

Comment: "these two arrays": `chars[a]` is not an array. It's an indexing of the array `chars`. That's the only array you have.

Comment: **−1** Changing the question fundamentally after answers have been posted. Voting to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's no end to it: as answers are posted the OP adds to the question.

Comment: Down vote for asking a different question in edit. All answers are for original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chars[a] + chars[b]` is simply adding two characters, this will do `integer` addition.

You need to oveload `+` operator with `string` type. Below statement will do the trick:

`attempt = attempt + chars[a] + chars[b]`.

EDIT: (ANSWER TO CHANGED QUESTION)

Before each time you use `attempt` make sure it does not contain any older strings, one way of doing this is :

```
while (a < 26 && b < 26) {
    attempt =  "";
    attempt = ( attempt + chars[a] ) + chars[b];
```

Answer (score 0):

`char` is an integer type in C++, so the `+` operator performs arithmetic addition, not concatenation.

You will want to construct an empty string, then append the desired characters to it using the overloaded `+=(char c)` operator:

```
string attempt;
attempt += chars[a];
attempt += chars[b];
```

The operator `+` is defined for appending a single `char` to a `string`, however one of the operands must be a `string`, so this won't work:

```
attempt = attempt + ( chars[a] + chars[b] );
```

But this will:

```
attempt = ( attempt + chars[a] ) + chars[b];
```

Fortunately, due to left-to-right evaluation the first expression `( attempt + chars[a] )` is evaluated first anyway, so the parenthesis can be omitted:

```
attempt = attempt + chars[a] + chars[b];
```

You could also use the `append( size_t, char )` method which you can chain because it returns a reference to itself:

```
string attempt;
attempt.append( 1, chars[a] ).append( 1, chars[b] );
```

There is no `append( char )` method, however.

Comment: while (a < 26 && b < 26) {
            attempt += chars[a];
            attempt += chars[b];
            b = b + 1;
            if (attempt == pwd) {
                cout << "The password is: " << attempt;
                break;
            }
            if (b >= 26) {
                a = a + 1;
                b = 0;
            }
        if (a >= 26 && b >= 26) {
            a = 0;
            b = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

Comment: @BlackHawkCH91 I moved your new code to your original question. Please explain what the **exact problem** is, because saying "it doesn't work" doesn't really tell us anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think, although I don't use C++, that char is kinda like a number combination that represents a character.

So when you add two char's together, you aren't concatenating... you are literally adding the two data values together.

i.e. the character A is represented as 65, B is represented as 66... so A + B is 131... I think that's outside the range of ASCII, so there is no character that corresponds with it, but that's the general gist.

I'll look into it bit more to see if I can find a more concrete answer, rather then just pointing out what I think is the issue.